# maxJsonLength exceeded logging with log4net ElasticSearch appender

Tags: json, exception, elasticsearch, log4net, log4net-appender

We are using the [log4net.ElasticSearch appender](https://www.nuget.org/packages/log4net.ElasticSearch/), to send application log messages to ElasticSearch.

We frequently log service requests and responses as context objects to log events, for debugging/support purposes - and it seems that sometimes responses when serialized can be too large, which results in the following exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException occurred
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property.
  Source=System.Web.Extensions
  StackTrace:
   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize(Object obj, StringBuilder output, SerializationFormat serializationFormat)
   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize(Object obj, SerializationFormat serializationFormat)
   at log4net.ElasticSearch.ExtensionMethods.ToJson[T](T self)
  InnerException:
```

Is there any way to increase this limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a pull request for the appender:

https://github.com/jptoto/log4net.ElasticSearch/blob/f5d122526f410d1294bc8d3aeb5a94379800f552/src/log4net.ElasticSearch/ExtensionMethods.cs

```
    public static string ToJson<T>(this T self)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        serializer.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;
        return serializer.Serialize(self);
    }
```

Comment: Very good idea - thanks - done! https://github.com/jptoto/log4net.ElasticSearch/pull/92